# You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error in multiple Selenium Python projects when chromedriver loads. They all start with these imports in case a specific library of selenium...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Recently I upgraded to Python selenium package 2.42.1, not sure if it is specific to those updates or a chromedriver thing? Has anyone else seen this, are there any documentation, and what if any are the potential problems.

I have found this on Windows 7 and Windows 8 OS's.

Answer (score 2):

There have been many tickets raised in ChromeDriver issue tracker.

Here's the main one:

[Chrome starts with message "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer."](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=799)

Please keep an eye on it for the latest progress.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved in [Chromedriver 2.11](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=799#c50). Upgrading should be sufficient:

`brew upgrade chromedriver`

However in my case, I was unable to upgrade to the latest Chromedriver version. Instead I had to uninstall  and then install Chromedriver again:

`brew install chromedriver 
brew uninstall chromedriver`

Comment: This is obviously only for Mac users

Answer (score -1):

I faced this issue while running selenium tests in chrome driver.
I've added

`<chrome.switches>test-type</chrome.switches>`

in to the POM file.

If you are running in command line u can add

```
-Dwebdriver.chrome.switches=--test-type
```

In Phyton try this one while instantiating a driver

```
desired_cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
desired_cap['chromeOptions'] = {}
desired_cap['chromeOptions']['args'] = ['--test-type']
```

Comment: Tried it with Selenium 2.41.0. Tried both `<chrome.switches>test-type</chrome.switches>` and `<webdriver.chrome.switches>test-type</webdriver.chrome.switches>`. In both cases I still see the warning from Chrome. Are you sure you do not have something else going on?

Comment: @SiKing would you share the log during the instantiation of the driver.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "log during the instantiation of the driver". I eventually got it to work using `ChromeOptions()`, which you subsequently have to pass to the `ChromeDriver()` constructor, but I would really like to find a solution that I do not have to pass to the constructor. Also, I cannot find anything anywhere on the Internet about "webdriver.chrome.switches"; are you sure you got the spelling right?

Comment: @SiKing I have updated my answer. Please check this out

Comment: As I said: The ChromeOptions way works perfectly fine. Your first two ways: pom and commandline -D switch do **not** work, at least for me.